# Remove Rows With Nulls/Empty in Column Indices

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists of strings for my data and a List of column indices for which a row needs to have at least one non-null value.

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
myList.Add(new List<string> { "a", "b" , "" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "", "c", "" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "d", "", "" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "e", "", "f" });
```

If my List for columnIndices is 1,2 then I'd like to find the optimal way for the third list (the one containing "d") to be dropped, since it only contains nulls/empties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
myList.RemoveAll(l => indices.All(i => l[i] == "")));
```

Assuming `indices` is an integer list containing the column indices that need to be empty strings.

Comment: This data is an example of a much larger dataset, the same for the indices. Is there a way to do this for each column index, for each row index, without being explicit?

Comment: this method should work just as well with more rows, when using more indices you could use a for loop to check the indices.

Comment: The for loop would remove it if any column has an empty for that value, but not check if all indices have at least one non-null value. I could have two for loops but was looking for a quicker linq method.

Comment: @MarkMcGown However judging from your question there is only one row in the dataset that has empty strings in the column indices you provide. It is therefore better to not use LINQ / RemoveAll() since that function will iterate through all rows, even when the one row is found. Just using foreach- or for-loops from which you can exit when you found the one row, therefore does not look like bad practice in this case, or you should elaborate more.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree linq would be overkill. It looks like my attempt to make the simplest case back-fired since the real data is several GB large. Imagining that, can you come up with a linq way to ensure each row that doesn't have at least one non-null value in the list of column indices is dropped?

Comment: You lost me there for a bit... you mean to say that you have multiple rows that have an empty string in all column indices you specify (or even more), and you therefore want to remove all of those rows?

Comment: That is correct. If a row has all values null for the list of column indices, it needs to be dropped.

Comment: @MarkMcGown I've updated my answer, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely for me:

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string> { "a", "b", "" },
    new List<string> { "", "c", "" },
    new List<string> { "d", "", "" },
    new List<string> { "e", "", "f" },
};

var columnIndices = new [] { 1, 2 };

List<List<string>> output =
    myList
        .Where(l => columnIndices.Any(i => l[i] != ""))
        .ToList();
```